# How to get the name of the music currently playing in spotify?

Tags: vim, spotify

I'm trying to find a way to display the music that's currently playing in the terminal and show on my vim statusline, I imagine there some temp file with the current song name, anyone knows where can i find it?

Answer (score 14):

Inspired by the `sp-metadata` function in `sp`, which is "a command-line client for Spotify's dbus interface" at https://gist.github.com/wandernauta/6800547, you can use the following command to get the track title:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player string:Metadata | sed -n '/title/{n;p}' | cut -d '"' -f 2
```

Comment: excellent. for anyone wondering, by extension, you can get this artist this way: 
`dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player string:Metadata | sed -n '/artist/{n;n;p}' | cut -d '"' -f 2`

Comment: also, if you only want to only display the information if the music is running, you can check the playback status this way:
`gdbus call --session --dest org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify --object-path /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player PlaybackStatus`