# Detect when the current song changes on Spotify

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, spotify

I'm working on a small personal project that involves getting the current Spotify song data.

The getting the metadata part is all figured out but I just need a way to detect when a song changes, like a script that triggers when the song changes, and I figured one of you might know something about this.

I was thinking maybe a script that runs on an interval and compares the current metadata with the last one saved, but maybe someone has a better idea.

EDIT (Solved, kinda): I ended up using a python script that keeps fetching the track information using dbus-send and writing the info to a file that I can easily parse.

Comment: Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/852366/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-music-currently-playing-in-spotify

Comment: Yes, that is already part of my script. But it offers no way of knowing when the song changes. Thank you though.

Comment: Interesting, I'm looking for the exact same solution...
Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855380/detect-the-end-of-a-spotify-track-with-applescript

Comment: I ended up using a python script that keeps fetching the track information using dbus-send and writing the info to a file that I can easily parse :)

Comment: Your idea of comparing the current metadata with the last saved one sounds convincing. Another idea might be to use the Spotify API to listen to real-time updates.

Comment: @SophiaLeal comparing the metadata seems like a good solution and a nice answer to your question. Would you be willing to share your Python script as an answer? ;)